# Construct $f: X\to Y$ such that $f(p)=p$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, proof-verification

> Let , $X=[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$ and $Y=\{0\}\times \left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$. Construct an example of a continuous map $f:X\to Y$ such that $f(p)=p$ for each $p\in Y$.

I construct a function as below :
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\left(0,\frac{1}{2}+y\right) & \text{ if }(x,y)\in[-1,1]\times\left[-1,-\frac{1}{2}\right]\\(0,y) & \text{ if }(x,y)\in [-1,1]\times\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]\\\left(0,\frac{1}{2}-y\right) & \text{ if }(x,y)\in[-1,1]\times \left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\end{cases}$$

Is my construction correct ? Please check.

If wrong please tell me where my mistake.

Comment: Your function isn't continuous.  At y = -1/2 and 1/2 the has 2 different values so it isn't a function and even if you replaced close intervals with open intervals so it is a function it's very discontinuous and -1/2 and 1/2.  I'm not sure why you thought you had to set different values if points outside the interval.  It was exactly the *wrong* approach if you want continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is a) not a function and b) is not continuous.

f(0,- 1/2) = {0, -1/2} and f(0, 1/2) = {1/2, 0} have two values so it is not a function.  It can be made a function by setting:

$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\left(0,\frac{1}{2}+y\right) & \text{ if }(x,y)\in[-1,1]\times\left[-1,-\frac{1}{2}\right)\\(0,y) & \text{ if }(x,y)\in [-1,1]\times\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)\\\left(0,\frac{1}{2}-y\right) & \text{ if }(x,y)\in[-1,1]\times \left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\end{cases}$

but then it would be discontinuous at $(x,1/2)$ and $(x,-1/2)$  The $\lim_{y\rightarrow\frac {1}{ 2}^+} = 1/2$ but $\lim_{y\rightarrow\frac {1}{ 2}^-} = 0$ s0 it isn't continuous.

Try $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\left(0,-\frac{1}{2}\right) & \text{ if }(x,y)\in[-1,1]\times\left[-1,-\frac{1}{2}\right]\\(0,y) & \text{ if }(x,y)\in [-1,1]\times\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]\\\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right) & \text{ if }(x,y)\in[-1,1]\times \left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\end{cases}$

Or if you want to be clever:

$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\left(0,-1-y\right) & \text{ if }(x,y)\in[-1,1]\times\left[-1,-\frac{1}{2}\right]\\(0,y) & \text{ if }(x,y)\in [-1,1]\times\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]\\\left(0,1-y\right) & \text{ if }(x,y)\in[-1,1]\times \left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\end{cases}$

Answer (score 2):

According to your definition, $f(0,-1/2)$ is being mapped to two distinct points : $(0,0)$ and $(0,-1/2)$. So it's not quite a function.